# Inputting multiple row entries by a factor in laravel

Tags: laravel, duplicates

I am attempting to recursively input a quantity of rows into a mysql database. The rows will all have the same product id but an incremental name given by product_id_incremental_number. My form is as follows:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h1>Add a new entry to the database</h1>
            <p class="lead">Add your entry below:</p>
            <hr>
            {!! Form::open(array('method'=>'POST',    'route'=>array('inventory.store'))) !!}
                     <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('production_id', 'Production ID', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('production_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('quantity', 'Quantity of chips:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::number('quantity', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                </div>
      {!! Form::submit('Create New Batch Entry', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

My controller is as follows:

```
    public function store()
    {
            $data = Input::all();
            $batch = $data->replicate($data['quantity']);
            $batch->save();

     }

        return Redirect::route('inventory.index')->with('flash_notice', "Batch Created");
    }
```

I know this isn't the full function to add incremental names to each of the items that would be in the batch, I haven't reached that point yet. My problem is that I cannot replicate an array to then insert each replicate of the batch into the database. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

TL;DR: It's a similar problem to ordering more than one pizza on an online cart, you just click a counter that increases the number of pizza that are added to the cart database.

Many thanks,
MF

Comment: I think you are using the `replicate()` function wrongly. The `replicate()` functions is a function of the `Model` class. This won't work, correct me if I'm wrong, since the `$data` variable is not a `Model`. Check [this](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_replicate) for more info.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to duplicate rows? If not, you could insert a new column 'quantity' in your table to make things more easy.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. What is `$batch` ? How does your database structure look? What do you expect as the final output in the database?

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen Thank you for your reply. I will look into replicate() in more depth. I want to duplicate rows as I am creating a batch input, each item in the batch input will have the same columns but different values in some columns. For example everything shares the same product code but will eventually have different serial numbers.

Comment: @GaryGreen $batch is an attempt to create a list of replicate inputs which I could then iterate over with another function. As an example I will iterate over all repeats to add unique serial numbers.